# Use Onclick to change an image

Tags: javascript

I have two DIVs on the left are thumbnail images and on the right I have one image. I am trying to click an image on the left side and have it replace the image on the right side. Currently when I select a thumbnail image I get the swirly indicator that the function has been called but the image isn't updated. Can this be completed with normal javascript or should JQuery be used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
    //  This function will display photos selected by user
     function showDirectory(){
         var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");
         for(var i=0;i<=myFiles.files.length; i++){
            var x = myFiles.files[i].name;
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += "<img onclick='switchImage("+x+")' src='"+x+"' style='width:40px; height:40px; margin:5px'>"
         }
     }
            
    function switchImage(e){
       document.getElementById("rightside").src=e;
    }
</script>
```

Show files in the Directory

```
    <div class="item" style="width: 70%; background-color: bisque; padding: 5px;">
       <img id="rightside" src="RightSide.jpg" alt="Picture of " style="height: 720px; width:720px">
        <p  style="color: #000; text-align: right;">Slide1.jpg</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the first code block in your question: it is not complete.

Comment: Element `"files"`? Element `"demo1"`? Could you please create a [mcve]? Read [ask]. And than [edit] to add some clarity about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Why is your first chunk of code unclosed? Where is the missing HTML? When do you call `showDirectory` ? Please...

Comment: Why are you assigning `document.getElementById("rightside").innerHTML` to an **image**? Hope you realise images do not have innerHTML, rather a `src` attribute. Have you done a research on how to use JS to change the src of an image?

Comment: I don't know why I am trying to assign innerHTML to an image. I didn't know we couldn't. Fairly new to this (six weeks maybe) trying to learn by trial and error using w3School as my reference. It's been a rough ride. I'll digest this post and work on this some more. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the innerHTML of an img element is not going to display the image. You need to create a link to the image to display it.

```html
<input type="file" id="files" multiple="" accept="image/*" onchange="showDirectory()">
<p id="demo1"></p>
<img id="rightside" style="height:720px; width:720px">
```

```js
function showDirectory(){
     var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");
     for(let i=0;i<=myFiles.files.length; i++){
        let f = myFiles.files[i];
        let e = document.createElement('img');
        e.src = URL.createObjectURL(f);
        e.onclick = () => {
            document.getElementById("rightside").src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(f);
        };
        document.getElementById("demo1").append(e);
     }
}
```

(This works on a blank about:blank page with minimal HTML)

Helpful Links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL